# How to install Virtualbox 5.1 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dpkg

I had Virtualbox 5.0 installed, but at every first VM start I got to execute the following command:

```
sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

So I decided to remove Virtualbox and install version 5.1 for Ubuntu 16.04. That was a bad decision. I can't get it working.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.
(Reading database ... 814705 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.1_5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.8-111374~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.1:
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0); however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.

$ sudo apt install libqt5x11extras5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libqt5x11extras5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libqt5x11extras5' has no installation candidate
```

**How can I get Virtualbox 5.1 installed on Ubuntu 16.04?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it manually from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libqt5x11extras5).

---

*P.S. I wonder, should it not be in the repo?*

Comment: It might not be in the repo right away, Ubuntu is usually more or less a year behind.

Comment: It is in the Universe repos.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libqt5x11extras5

Comment: @Terrance So it should be there!

Comment: Yeah, it's there.  It almost sounds like OP doesn't have the universe repository enabled in the sources.list file.